# Converting IQueryable generated by Entity Framework 6 model into SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My application was originally built using Entity Framework 4 and a database other than SQL Server.  I wrote a function which translated an `IQueryable` into the raw SQL that would be sent to the database when it was executed.  I needed this because the database I was using had no way I knew of to capture the SQL that was sent to the server for executing -- there was no tool like the SQL Profiler tool in SQL Server.  I needed the SQL so I could test the query that was generated and make changes as necessary to optimize performance.

I recently upgraded the application to Entity Framework 6 and the function to convert the `IQueryable` to SQL doesn't work any more.  Here's the function:

```
public static string GetSql<T>( this IQueryable<T> query ) {
    string sql = ( (ObjectQuery<T>) query ).ToTraceString();

    ObjectQuery<T> q = query as ObjectQuery<T>;

    // Loop over the parameters in REVERSE ORDER!
    foreach ( ObjectParameter p in q.Parameters.OrderByDescending( p => p.Name ) ) {
        string pName = ":" + p.Name;

        if ( p.Value == null )
            sql = sql.Replace( pName, "NULL" );
        else {
            switch ( p.Value.GetType().Name ) {
                case "Boolean":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, (bool) p.Value ? "1" : "0" ); break;
                case "Byte":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, "0x" + ( (byte) p.Value ).ToString( "X2" ) ); break;
                case "DateTime":        sql = sql.Replace( pName, "'" + ( (DateTime) p.Value ).ToString() + "'" ); break;
                case "DateTimeOffset":    sql = sql.Replace( pName, "'" + ( (DateTimeOffset) p.Value ).ToString() + "'" ); break;
                case "Decimal":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, ( (Decimal) p.Value ).ToString() ); break;
                case "Double":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, ( (Double) p.Value ).ToString() ); break;
                case "Guid":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, "'" + ( (Guid) p.Value ).ToString( "D" ) + "'" ); break;
                case "Int16":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, ( (Int16) p.Value ).ToString() ); break;
                case "Int32":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, ( (Int32) p.Value ).ToString() ); break;
                case "Int64":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, ( (Int64) p.Value ).ToString() ); break;
                case "Single":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, ( (Single) p.Value ).ToString() ); break;
                case "String":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, "'" + (String) p.Value + "'" ); break;
                case "UInt16":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, ( (UInt16) p.Value ).ToString() ); break;
                case "UInt32":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, ( (UInt32) p.Value ).ToString() ); break;
                case "UInt64":            sql = sql.Replace( pName, ( (UInt64) p.Value ).ToString() ); break;
            }
        }
    }
        return sql;
}
```

This doesn't work because the `IQueryable` returned by EF6 does not descend from `ObjectQuery`.  It's a `DbQuery`.  Calling the `ToString` method returns the SQL with the parameters in it.  I want to replace the parameters in the query with the values actually passed, as the code above did, so I can just paste the query into the query tool without editing it.

There doesn't seem to be a `Parameters` collection in the `DbQuery` class, at least no property with that name.  How do I get this to work in EF6?

Comment: Does `query.ToString()` not work?

Comment: It returns a query string that looks like `SELECT [Extent1].LastName, [Extent1].FirstName FROM Employees AS [Extent1] WHERE EmpNo = @p_linq_0`.  What I want is the query to read `SELECT [Extent1].LastName, [Extent1].FirstName FROM Employees AS [Extent1] WHERE EmpNo = 1234`.  The code in the function above did that, but `query.ToString` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework 6 provides a flexible way of tracking the queries that are sent for execution to the database server.

`Logging and Intercepting Database Operations`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

```
using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 

    var blog = context.Blogs.First(b => b.Title == "One Unicorn"); 

    blog.Posts.First().Title = "Green Eggs and Ham"; 

    blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Title = "I do not like them!" }); 

    context.SaveChangesAsync().Wait(); 
}
```

Comment: While that's a nice feature and is very useful, it still does not do what my function does.  Yes, it outputs the SQL and the values of the parameters, but it doesn't REPLACE the parameters in the query with their values.  That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Having read further down the page, I may be able to get what I want using the `DatabaseLogFormatter` mechanism.  The problem is that switching to this mechanism means I have to wait until the `IQueryable` is actually executed before getting the query.  My code is sprinkled with calls to `Debug.WriteLine( query.GetSql() )` to send the SQL to the Output window in VS BEFORE the query is executed.  Changing this is not a trivial problem.